# Looking for a way to eliminate temp database storage in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API written with ASP.NET Core 3.1 which is hosted on a server.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Packet packet)
{
    var result = await _collectionRepository.AddCollection(JsonSerializer.Serialize(resultPacket));
    return Ok(result);
}
```

This API is consumed by around more than 100 client machines to post some packet and all client machines post data in concurrent API calls.

In server where API is hosted I am using MongoDB to store data temporarily and periodically I am reading the data from mongo db collection and write them into files and deleting the records what already read.

As you see I am depending on some temp store and then writing into files.

Question is, is there any feature available with dot net core where I can eliminate the temp store writing or at least I can eliminate some database store and use something else, please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there is something "built in" to .Net Core that would magically make this process easier.  If you are trying to offload work from the API and database, then perhaps the best option is to simply put the packet of data to be processed into a message queue and let a background "worker" process handle them as time allows (if not time sensitive).  If you're self hosting, you can use something like RabbitMQ or in the cloud (Azure) you have options like Azure Storage Queues or Service Bus.  Then create a worker (console app running as a service, or Azure Function) that polls the queue and processes the data as needed (exports to a file).  The queue is somewhat equivalent to your MongoDB in that it server as a temp storage location, but a queue may be a more appropriate intermediate location than the DB and it scales very well.